# Cleanest way to implement optimized and non-optimesed versions of a function?

Tags: python

for a university project I want to implement some code in python. Later on, parts of it should be replaced with calls to native CUDA code.

Right now, I was thinking about putting a module wide switch `OPTIMIZED` in my module.

```
def set_optimized(b):
    # possible check for CUDA device first
    OPTIMIZED = b

def my_fun(arg1, arg2):
    if OPTIMIZED:
       # some c-calls here
       return retval
    else:
       # some python code here
       return retval
```

This implementation has some nice properties:

- Test cases can easily compare optimized and non-optimized versions in result & performance.
- For every optimized function there is a non-optimized backup. For example on machines without CUDA device, I suppress the switch to the optimized version and the programm still runs without changes to the code.

Another option would be to implement all functions as methods of a `class NonOpt`. The functions could be overriden with optimized versions in `class Opt(NonOpt)`.
It feels like this option has less boilerplate code, but comes with a disadvantage: the algorithm which instantiate and use the class has to be aware of the underlying opt/nonopt versions.

Is there a canonical way to do this? Or is it a bad idea anyway and I'm overlooking something fundamental?

Sidenote: To me this question is quite general. I've stumbled over this problem in the past, when I wanted to maintain optimized and non-optimized code in Julia. Whenerver I had to change the math, I could simply change the easy-readable non-optimized version. The testcases would tell me, wether I've achived the same results in the more complicated optimized version.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another option to your list and to possibly "segregate" your functions is using `if` statement during import. Depends on your style, just make sure they will end up with the same name and contains the same function names.

```
if OPTIMIZED:
    from optimized import mymodule
else:
    from non_optimized import mymodule
```

Another method is called monkey-patching (replacing the imported methods during runtime).